# how can I use math environment for a non English language?

Tags: polyglossia

I am trying to print in for Sanskrit language but math environment does not print Sanskrit in fractions.

I am using this $\dfrac{/जी.श}{५}$ and have tried other shorthands too. Sanskrit text is showing fine outside math environment and English text in math environment in the same document works well too just Sanskrit text does not print in math environment

Comment: It might be possible using the `unicode-math` package. I would suggest looking at the documentation here: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.pdf and investigating how to get what you want. If you do succeed, provide an answer to your question for the benefit of those who follow.

Comment: `\frac{\text{/जी.श}}{\text{५}}$` should work (`\text` from `amsmath` package)

Comment: it did work! thanks.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

`\text` from `amsmath` allows text at the right size (you need something similar even for Latin scripts)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Lohit-Devanagari.ttf}


\begin{document}

\devanagarifont
$\frac{\text{/जी.श}}{\text{५}}$


\[\frac{\text{/जी.श}}{\text{५}}\]

\end{document}


\begin{document}

\devanagarifont
$\frac{\text{/जी.श}}{\text{५}}$


\[\frac{\text{/जी.श}}{\text{५}}\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use text in math, you need to specify it as text. On the other hand, you can define the Sanskrit digits to work in text and math without further hassle.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{sanskrit}
\setmainfont{ITF Devanagari}[NFSSFamily=devn]
\newfontfamily{\latinfont}{Latin Modern Roman}

\DeclareSymbolFont{sanskritdigits}{\encodingdefault}{devn}{m}{n}
\Umathcode`०="7 \symsanskritdigits "0966
\Umathcode`१="7 \symsanskritdigits "0967
\Umathcode`२="7 \symsanskritdigits "0968
\Umathcode`३="7 \symsanskritdigits "0969
\Umathcode`४="7 \symsanskritdigits "096A
\Umathcode`५="7 \symsanskritdigits "096B
\Umathcode`६="7 \symsanskritdigits "096C
\Umathcode`७="7 \symsanskritdigits "096D
\Umathcode`८="7 \symsanskritdigits "096E
\Umathcode`९="7 \symsanskritdigits "096F


\begin{document}

$\dfrac{\text{जी.श}}{५}$ $\dfrac{३४५}{८९}$

{\latinfont Text:} ०१२३४५६७८९

{\latinfont Math:} $०१२३४५६७८९$

\end{document}
```

[image]